# How to make filter based on select and checkbox tags?

Tags: javascript, angular, camunda, camunda-modeler

I want  to  make  filter which  will help me organize my  table  data  based  on it's priority  value(  for example  i  have  three  priority  value: very  important,  important  and  not  so   important and   also  i  have three  option values  inside  my select  tag with  same name, when i  choose  one  of  this  select  option  for  example   very  important i should   see  in  my  table  only  this tr data's  which  have  this  priority and  also  i  need to  use main  checkbox  input  for  select/not select  all tr-s  which  are  shown on table, here is  my  angular+ javscrit  code  but  in my  case  i can't  choose only  filtered  tr-s from my  table instead  i  can  choose all   the 
 data from this  table:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#mySelector').change( function(){
      var selection = $(this).val();
      $('table')[selection? 'show' : 'hide']();

      if (selection) {
        $.each($('#myTable tbody tr'), function(index, item) {
          $(item)[$(item).is(':contains('+ selection  +')')? 'show' : 'hide']();
        });
      }

    });
});
              <select> 
>            <option value='important'>აირჩიე</option>
>            <option value='very important'>very important</option>
>            <option value='middle important'>middle important</option>
>            <option value='not so important'>not so important</option>
>         </select>
>         </div>
>         </div>
>             </div>
>             <table name ="table" id="myTable" class="table table-hover  table-list-search" data-table="order-table" style="width:100%;" cellspacing="0">
>                 <thead>
>                     <tr>
>                         <th style="width:80px; height:25px;"><input style="width:25px; height:25px;" type="checkbox" id="checkAll" ng-click="selectAll()" /></th>
>                         
>                         <th style="width:140px;">id</th>
>                         <th style="width:305px;">organizationNameEN</th>
>                         <th style="width:305px;">organizationNameGE</th>
>                         <th style="width:305px;">priority</th>
>                          <th>&nbsp;</th>
>                     </tr>           
>                 </thead>
>                 <tbody ng-repeat="item in jsonData">
>                     <tr>
>                         <td><input type="checkbox" ng-change="sync(selected[item.id],item)"  ng-checked="isChecked(item.id)" name="checkData" ng-model="selected[item.id]" ng-false-value="undefined" /></td> 
>                 
>                         <td>{{item.id}}</td>
>                         <td>{{item.organizationNameEN}}</td>
>                          <td>{{item.organizationNameGE}}</td>   
>                          <td>{{item.priority}}</td>                   
>                          <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="toggle($index)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button></td>
> 
> 
>         </tr>
```

Any idea how can i implement this logic( i mean selection filter ) in angular?
when i fileter table like this:[image]

i want to choose only selected value on main checkbox clikc and put this data in selectedDocuments,
how should i implement this logic ?
here  are  several  subjects  i am interested in:

1. is  there  any  better  way  to make  pipe  in camunda form?
   2.can i  put  in  array  only  those   tr-s value  whose  visibility  isn't none or  it  is  bad  idea?